# How to remove leading and trailing zero from a time

Tags: mysql

from

00:00:10.137000 --->  10.137

Comment: Please provide how that output was produced and what "update" was done.  Suggest writing a test case to show the problem.

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE script of your table.

Comment: UPDATE tbl t 
inner join (select id,
TIMEDIFF(x_time , first_value(x_time) over(order by id asc)) as result_diff
             from tbl
            )   x on t.id=x.id
  set time = result_diff

Comment: this is how it was created. thank you in advance. I'm sorry if I was not able to get it soon.

Comment: In reality, the way that dates and times appear when they are queried from the database are more about how the client side chooses to display the values, rather than how they are "saved" in the database ..... essentially, if your column holds some kind of date/time, then it will inherently have corresponding year/month/day/hour/minute/second/millisecond, etc. values.  If you want to "see" that date/time in a certain way, then that would usually be some formatting that gets applied by the client-side application

Comment: Yes, I understand, also the input is a string data type which  from I really have no control. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your SHOW CREATE TABLE for t and x to allow testing, try this

UPDATE tbl t inner join (select id, TIMEDIFF(x_time , first_value(x_time) over(order by id asc)) as result_diff from tbl ) x on t.id=x.id set time = TRIM(BOTH '0' from result_diff)

Let us know your results, please.